# Finding a path that includes specific nodes in a directed graph

Tags: graph

I have a directed graph, and a set U of nodes of that graph.
I want to find out if there is a path(not necessarily a simple path) that includes all nodes in the set U. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Why do you think that the approach you decided to implement is not efficient enough?

Comment: Look for "Hamilton Path" or "Hamilton Cycle".

Comment: "Hamilton Path" is only applicable to undirected graphs,and it must be a simple path.

Comment: I was thinking about choosing some arbitrary node in U and using BFS, but i'm not sure how to continue from there

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Create a graph G'=(U,E') with e \in E' iff e's target can be reached from e's source in the original graph G. (The exact computation of reachability depends on if you allow nodes to be visited twice.)

Now, what do you have to check for G' in order to solve your problem?

Comment: There must be at least one node in G' that have edges to each one of the other nodes,but i'm not sure if it guarantees the existence of the path. And creating G' will take O(n^2) time,no?

Comment: @user1758674: If I understand your problem correctly, I think this is neither sufficient nor necessary. Construction will require at least O(E'), which might be O(n^2) in the worst case.